# Trueness of Knowledge and its value

Tags: knowledge

Is it reasonable to distrust any knowledge we know? Is there any value of knowledge when we deny its trueness?

My thought:

It is impossible for us to know a specific truth or order of universe with only finite observations; instead, we can only verify them. For instance, scientific knowledge are tentative and are subjected to new evidances. It is always a cycle of hypothesis and confirmation of the theory until it is proven to be false. We may assume it is true once it is verified. However, as said before, we can never tell the trueness of the theory as a form of knowledge.

There are many well-established and recognized theories that have been verified to be true for a long time. While it is possibly to be true, is it ignorant to distrust such knowledges?

I would appreciate any correction of my flaws in my thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is impossible for us to know a specific truth or order of universe
>   with only finite observations; instead, we can only verify them. For
>   instance, scientific knowledge are tentative and are subjected to new
>   evidances. It is always a cycle of hypothesis and confirmation of the
>   theory until it is proven to be false. We may assume it is true once
>   it is verified.

You're mixing up verificationism and falisificationism here. I believe you hint at the idea of Popper. We only have finite observations. In order to circumvent induction we have to formulate hypotheses and try, with all our might, to falsify them. When there not yet falsified then they are our best explanation. If they get falsified we have to drop them. I'll just note that there are arguments against that views in philosophy of science.

But this isn't even that important for your question. It's more about whether the results we get out of scientific processes are to be believed or if they are only functional but can't result in truths. The former would be scientific realism, the latter would be scientific antirealism. There is, however, a position inbetween called "scientific structuralism" which seems to be quite defensible. The SEP can provide articles about the issue.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-realism/

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structural-realism/

So your position seems to hold scientific realism at least possible, as you say that we can't tell the trueness of a theory. More on that later. These positions then come into play with the problem of scientific progress: whether science progresses and how we should think about it in terms of truth.

More here:

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-progress/#ReaIns

> However, as said before, we can never tell the trueness of the theory
>   as a form of knowledge.

So this is not a default position. But, assuming you can argue for it, if we go from here we could find value in two ways. Firstly, while they might still be wrong, they could be closer to truth. Popper argues in that way. You'll find a bit more in the third article. Secondly, even if they might be completely wrong, they could still have instrumental value.

You asked:

> Is it reasonable to distrust any knowledge we know?

No, in general it isn't. But it depends on whether we think there is some acceptable theory of justification and *also* what we think truth is. This is a huge field. But let's take one example.

If we think that knowledge is justified true belief (that can deal with Gettier cases... I'll rather add that before someone lynches me) then your position would have to commit to the idea that we are justified in doubting justification in general because, often times, it has turned out wrong. This seems contradictory. Does it look different if we just apply it to science? Well not really. Just because theories before have turned out to be wrong this does not undermine our justification to accept current theories. (If "accept" means that we should believe that they show something true is a different matter connect to all sorts of issues, as I've tried to show beforehand.) After all, this sceptical approach has no justification itself.

I'll leave you with a bit of Wittgenstein. In *On Certainty* he writes: "If you tried to doubt everything you would not get as far as doubting anything. The game of doubting itself presupposes certainty.". I believe this is really important. The word "knowledge" does not require complete certainty. Hence it's fine to say that we know something even if there's a chance it can turn out to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Fallibilism : I wonder if this is an epistemology that would meet your requirements. The definition of fallibilism is a matter of some controversy but I take fallibilism to have two components.

One is the conjoint assumption that few would deny, namely that (a) none of our beliefs is certainly true and (b) we are prone to error. Neither entails the other but the two fit well together. At the very least both appear to be true.

The other is that S can know that p even if S lacks logically conclusive evidence to justify her in believing that p.

We certainly use the term 'know' when this condition is met. There is a bunch of tulips in S's room. T, a normally reliable witness, has just told her this. S has seen someone go into the room with a  bunch of tulips and come out without them. She herself has just looked into the room and what in conditions of normal illumination looks like a bunch of tulips is on the table.

This would not satisfy the condition of Cartesian knowledge. Descartes but most of us would accept that, all else equal, S knows that there is a bunch of tulips in the room.

S's belief is not certainly true and she is just as prone to error as the rest of us. S lacks logically conclusive evidence to justify her in believing that there is a bunch of tulips in the room. But do we need more than fallibilism offers ?

We need a concept of knowledge that is serviceable, not drastically Cartesianly immune from error. (A serviceable concept of knowledge is a functional concept; what counts as knowledge are beliefs about our environment that can guide our actions to a successful outcome (EJ Craig, 'The Practical Explication of Knowledge', 'Aristotelian Society, 87, 1986-7 : 215.) Fallibilism allows S to know that p on the basis of less than logically conclusive evidence, yet leaves S's and everyone else's knowledge - belief based on less than logically conclusive evidence - permanently open to revision, correction. The bunch of flowers which on the evidence described S believed that there is a bunch of tulips in her room at time t may no longer be there at t+1 and yet S retain her belief, which no longer amounts to knowledge.

Do you need a different epistemology than this ? One tighter in what it will allow as knowledge. I don't think I do but it's your question. I can only give my own answer.

Of course no philosophical view is quite free from difficulty. (a) says that none of our beliefs is certainly true. But if I believe that I believe something, then this belief does seem certainly true. I don't know the best way of dealing with this but it strikes me as a special class of belief with which a generally serviceable theory of knowledge can pragmatically work without resolving.

Comment: Generally I agree with this (with upvote), but the statement "if I believe that I believe something, then this belief does seem certainly true" makes me wonder.  This would be true if we were rational.  If not, I could believe something rationally and state explicitly what I think my belief is, but when I make a choice from a gut feeling I choose something different.

Comment: @Frank Hubeny. I think you are reading my statement more deeply than I intended ! I don't disagree with what you say but I had in mind something different. Take an amnesiac, X,  who cannot remember any of his or her beliefs. However, X believes (Belief 1) that he or she does have a particular belief (Belief 2) only it can't be brought to mind. X may be wrong about having Belief 2  but it seems certainly true that X does believe (Belief 1) that he or she has a belief (Belief 2).  Does that clarify? Best - GT